# Can't install the Wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have troubles installing plugins I got with a Theme I purchased on ThemeForest. The plugins with the Theme aren't zipped as usual. They all come like this

nameoftheplugin > (many folders like "assets", "css", "js", ...)

I tried to move the folder in the wp-content/plugins directory but nothing happens. Is there a way I can install theses plugins ? Usually I install WP plugins by uploading a .zip file so I'm lost here...

Thank you guys !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not off topic.  He has a question about wordpress plugins and tagged the question with wordpress and wordpress-plugin.

Comment: You *paid* for the theme, ask in their support channels

Comment: @Musik8101 well maybe those tags are for wordpress-developer and plugins developers not for regular users

Answer (score 0):

Themes and plugins are different.

Upload your Theme to wp-content/themes/ directory instead

Comment: I know. Sorry, maybe I didn't explain well. In the theme I purchased are some Premium plugins which are "included" in the Theme but they are not in .zip format so I don't know how to install them.

Comment: Yea don't worry about anything to do with themes, I added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are confused is that the folders like you mentioned nameoftheplugin > (many folders like "assets", "css", "js", ...)   Those are normally compressed into zip files.  If you have a program that does that you can just zip that main folder that has the name of the plugin and it will compress all of those folders in to a zip that you can upload as normal.

If you are on a mac, you can simply right click and select compress folder. Then you can upload the zip as normal.

If you don't have software to zip the folder.  You can use FTP either through a third party client or your hosting backend.  If you have cpanel you can use ftp there.  Then instead of uploading zip files.  You will go to  your public html folder > wp-content > plugins    and then drop the plugin name folder in there.

Either way will get you to upload the plugin.  You are just seeing the plugin folders unzipped for the first time so it can be a little confusing.

Go ahead and mark this solved.